# An EOF bug in CLion

Tags: c, clion

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Checking whether the value of (getchar() != EOF) is 1,
  when not reaching the EOF*/
main() {
    int c;

    printf("Please enter character:\n");
    while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
        printf("%d\t", c);
    }
    printf("%d - at EOF\n", c);
}
```

I have run this code in CLion, but there has been a problem that the content in the first `printf()` haven't appeared until I entered some words.

There's an example.

```
error
^D
Please enter character:
1   1   1   1   1   1   0 - at EOF
```

I know it's probably because I have disabled the option run.processes.with.pty in Registry, since the sentence 'Please enter character:' is at right place when the option is available. But if I don't do that, I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send an EOF. In addition, it seems the result can be correct only when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in a new empty line after characters.

Platform: Windows 10, Toolchain: MinGW

BTW, I've also tried Cygwin. The same problem occurred again. Any idea?

Comment: Because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you have: `while (c = (getchar() != EOF)) {`

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator precedence.  [@Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)

`c = getchar() != EOF` is the same as `c = (getchar() != EOF)`, certainly not what OP wants.

```
// while (c = getchar() != EOF)
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

---

> but there has been a problem that the content in the first printf() haven't appeared until I entered some words.

`stdout` is usually buffered.  It might be *line* buffered or *fully buffered* or not at all.  Use `fflush(stdout)` to insure output is posted.

```
printf("Please enter character:\n");
fflush(stdout); //add
while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
  printf("%d\t", c);
  fflush(stdout); //add
}
printf("%d - at EOF\n", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
c = getchar() != EOF
```

Is really just

```
c = (getchar() != EOF)
```

What you want is

```
(c = getchar()) != EOF
```

Many compilers will generate warnings if you use `c = getchar() != EOF`

```
$ cc -c test.c -Wall -Wextra
test.c:5:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main() {
 ^~~~
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:12: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
            ^
```

This is why it is recommended to enable warnings. For new projects, I would consider `-Wall -Wextra` to be the bare minimum.